# Почему у меня не получается заменить QGroupBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qmainwindow, qgroupbox

При повторном вызове кнопки просто очищаются

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize, QRect
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,QCheckBox, QWidget,QGroupBox,QRadioButton

from PyQt6 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWidgets
import sys
class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window22')
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(1099, 700))
        self.set_test('TEST1',1)

        self.button_next = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_next.setObjectName(u"button_next")
        self.button_next.setGeometry(QRect(770, 640, 261, 71))
        self.button_next.setText("next")
        self.button_next.clicked.connect(lambda:self.set_test('TEST2',2))
    def set_test(self,text,s):
        if s-1!=0:
            for button in self.findChild(QtWidgets.QGroupBox, f'groupBox_{s-1}').findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton):
                button.deleteLater()
        groupBox = QGroupBox(self)
        groupBox.setObjectName(f"groupBox_{s}")
        groupBox.setGeometry(QRect(30, 140, 631, 461))
        radioButton = QRadioButton(groupBox)
        radioButton.setObjectName(f"radioButton_1_{s}")
        radioButton.setGeometry(QRect(10, 30, 561, 51))
        radioButton.setStyleSheet(u"QRadioButton{font: 15pt Helvetica MS;} QRadioButton::indicator { width: 15px; height: 15px;};")
        radioButton_2 = QRadioButton(groupBox)
        radioButton_2.setObjectName(f"radioButton_2_{s}")
        radioButton_2.setGeometry(QRect(10, 150, 591, 51))
        radioButton_2.setStyleSheet(u"QRadioButton{font: 15pt Helvetica MS;} QRadioButton::indicator { width: 15px; height: 15px;};")
        radioButton.setText(text)
        radioButton_2.setText(text)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Test()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше объясните что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не уверен что понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать.

Если вы создаете виджет после показа главного окна
(это то, что у вас происходит после нажатия кнопки `button_next`),
вы должны показать этот виджет:

```
    ...
    groupBox.show()
    ...
    radioButton.show()
    radioButton_2.show()
    ...
```

или вставить вмджеты в менеджер компановки.
Мой пример это второй случай.

Кроме этого вам надо изучить [**Qt Main Window Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Научитесь использовать менеджеры компоновки: [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

---

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize, QRect
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,\
    QCheckBox, QWidget,QGroupBox,QRadioButton
from PyQt6 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWidgets
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window22')
# ???        self.setFixedSize(QSize(1099, 600))
        self.resize(QSize(1099, 600))
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                 # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                                # + 
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                  # + 

        self.set_test('TEST1', 1)

        self.button_next = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_next.setObjectName(u"button_next")
        self.button_next.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 261, 71))
        self.button_next.setText("next")
        self.button_next.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_test('TEST2', 2))
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_next)
        
    def set_test(self, text, s):
        if s-1 != 0:
            '''
            for button in self.findChild(
                    QtWidgets.QGroupBox, 
                    f'groupBox_{s-1}').findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton):
                button.deleteLater()
            '''
            groupBox = self.findChild(QGroupBox, f'groupBox_{s-1}')
            if groupBox:
                groupBox.deleteLater()
            else:
                return
            
        groupBox = QGroupBox(self)
        groupBox.setTitle(text)        
        groupBox.setObjectName(f"groupBox_{s}")
        groupBox.setGeometry(QRect(30, 140, 631, 461))
# !        groupBox.show()
        
        radioButton = QRadioButton(groupBox)
        radioButton.setObjectName(f"radioButton_1_{s}")
        radioButton.setGeometry(QRect(10, 30, 561, 51))
        radioButton.setStyleSheet(u"QRadioButton{font: 15pt Helvetica MS;} QRadioButton::indicator { width: 15px; height: 15px;};")
        radioButton_2 = QRadioButton(groupBox)
        radioButton_2.setObjectName(f"radioButton_2_{s}")
        radioButton_2.setGeometry(QRect(10, 150, 591, 51))
        radioButton_2.setStyleSheet(u"QRadioButton{font: 15pt Helvetica MS;} QRadioButton::indicator { width: 15px; height: 15px;};")
        radioButton.setText(text)
        radioButton_2.setText(text)
        
# !        radioButton.show()
# !        radioButton_2.show()
        
        self.layout.insertWidget(0, groupBox) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]